# Property injection for members of an interface

Tags: c#, autofac

I can do property injection by using the following code:

```
builder.RegisterType<ListViewModel>()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

This injects dependencies for all properties. But sometimes I only want to do property injection for members of an interface:

```
public interface IHasCommonServices
{
    ISession Session { get; set; }
    IEventPublisher EventPublisher { get; set; }
}

public class ListViewModel : IHasCommonServices
{
    // Inject dependencies for these properties
    public ISession Session { get; set; }
    public IEventPublisher EventPublisher { get; set; }

    // Don't inject for these properties
    public ListItemViewModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Is something like the following possible?

```
builder.RegisterType<ListViewModel>()
    .InjectForInterface<IHasCommonServices>();
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to implement this myself, but with no success (I don't have much programming experiences). After some more research, I decided to switch back to constructor injection.

Comment: Most of the time constructor injection is a better choice. It insures that your object is initialized with all required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but I think in most cases you can get away with:

```
.PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringFlags.PreserveSetValues);
```

If you need to have a bit more fine-grained control you can use OnActivated:

```
builder.Register<ListViewModel>()
       .As<IHasCommonServices>()
       .OnActivated(c => 
                    {
                        c.Instance.Session = c.Context.Resolve<ISession>();
                        c.Instance.EventPublisher = c.Context.Resolve<IEventPublisher>();
                    });
```

It's a little-bit tedious, but I don't think you would often need to do much property injection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, that should work in most cases, thanks!